# how to post a html without reload the page in ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

Does anyone know how can I post a html without reload the page in jquery or c# .net?

Example:

I have get a urllink in the page with the following link (dial.html?PhoneNumber=0465254245). When I clicked on the link, how can I post this url without reload the page with ajax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple way is using the shorthand AJAX call.

```
$.post('dial.html?PhoneNumber=0465254245', function(data) {
  $('.result').html(data); // .result is the class where you want the page to be
});
```

The long way is the following,

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: url, //Your URL
  data: data, 
  success: success,
  dataType: dataType
});
```

Refer [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) for a comprehensive options, including sample codes.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
$("#link").click(function(){
    $.post("dial.html?PhoneNumber=0465254245", function(data){
        alert("Post completed");
    }
}
```

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Answer (score 0):

For variety to the other two answers lets use [jQuery Get](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/)

Request the `dial.html?PhoneNumber=0465254245` page, but ignore the return results.

```
$("YOUR_SELECTOR").click(function(){
    $.get("dial.html?PhoneNumber=0465254245");
});
```

If you want to catch a returned value:

```
$("YOUR_SELECTOR").click(function(){
    $.get("dial.html?PhoneNumber=0465254245", function(returnedvalue) {
      alert("Value Returned: " + returnedvalue);
    });
});
```

Helpful links on `jQuery AJAX`:

- http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/
- http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/
- http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Cheers!